# New 802.11ax router problems

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, wireless-router

I just installed a new router (Asus RT-AX86U0) at home which seems to work great on all devices except my work laptop. The laptop connects through Cisco AnyConnect VPN to an Intel Wireless AC 8260 adapter, and while it does actually connect, several things do not work such as Microsoft Outlook, IE, Teams. The new router is somehow blocking these programs from loading. Other things like shared drives and Chrome work fine. My router settings are set to 'enabled' for all Passthrough settings in the GUI. Interestingly, if I turn off my new router and use my old router (Apple Airport Extreme A1470), the problem goes away and everything works. So, it seems that there is a setting in the Asus, but I don't know what it might be. Of course, corporate IT says to get a different router. Any thoughts?

Comment: Get the 8/18 update https://www.asus.com/ca-en/Networking/RT-AX86U/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: Yep.. I did update it upon initial configuration/installation.